# Internet explorer document mode how does it work?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, document, mode

I have a web page which works perfectly under IE7. The header contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

If I open the same page under IE8, then it does not work. If I open Developer Tools dialog, then I see that

```
Document mode - IE7 standards
Browser mode - IE8 compat view
```

If I change them to

```
Document mode - IE7 standards
Browser mode - IE7 or IE8
```

it still does not work.

If I change it to

```
Document mode - IE8
Browser mode -  IE8
```

then the page appears fine.

How the browser knows that the document mode is IE7 standard by default? and as the page appears in IE7 correctly, then why IE8 can not show it in IE7 browser mode with IE7 standard? It should act as an IE7 browser, right?

Thanks
Zoltan

Comment: You specify `loose.dtd`, it will enable "almost standard mode" in IE8 (there was not something like that in IE7). Change to `strict.dtd` or - better - just use `<!doctype html>` to request HTML 5 and proper `<meta>` according to IE version.